# MySQL Query from 3 tables (Count)

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

```
Mark
id_mark
mark_name

example record:
1, 'Ford'
2, 'Fiat'
```

---

```
Model
id_model
id_mark
mondel_name

example record:
1, 1, 'Focus'
2, 2, 'Panda'
```

---

```
Adds
id_adds
id_model
name
price
etc.

example records:
1 1 'My ad', 20000
2 1 'My ad2', 30000
3 2 'My ad3', 30000
```

How to execute a query that returned result (Mark Adds Count) example:

```
    Ford 2
    Fiat 1

2 and 1 count
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two joins. I've specified the second as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that it may return 0 for makes which have no associated ads.  `Mark` joins through `Model` to `Adds`.

```
SELECT
  mark_name,
  COUNT(id_adds) AS num_ads
FROM
  Mark JOIN Model ON Mark.id_mark = Model.id_mark
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Adds ON Model.id_model = Adds.id_model
GROUP BY mark_name
```

Comment: I think it's better to group by by id_mark. I think its primary key of mark table. The performance will be better.

Comment: Mark.id_model? Column id_model is in Model only.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  mark_name,
  COUNT(id_adds) AS num_adds
FROM  Mark
 LEFT JOIN Model ON Mark.id_mark = Model.id_mark
 LEFT JOIN Adds ON Model.id_model = Adds.id_model
GROUP BY Mark.id_mark
```

Comment: group by id_mark or not ? grouping by id_model will return bad results.

Comment: in this particular case group by model would work, but I think Kousalik you are right - it should be by mark, I edited the post - thank you

Comment: Mark.id_model? Column id_model is in Model only.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select mark.mark_name, count(adds.id_adds) from adds join model on adds.id_model = model.id_model join mark on model.id_mark = mark.id_mark group by mark.id_mark;
```

i am not 100% sure but something like this should work

Comment: You can edit your answer and mark your code as code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` "button". Or by putting 4spaces at the start of every row with code.